# How to refresh amount on checkbox click in Android?

Tags: android

I have 2 checkboxes and each is associated with amount let say checkbox1 = 50 and checkbox2=100 and default amount lets say 200. Now when user clicks on any of the checkbox then default amount should get updated accordingly.

If user clicks on checkbox1 then amount should be 200+50 = 250 and if he uncheck the checkbox then amount should get reset to 200.Same for checkbox2.

How to refresh this amount? any ideas.

Thanks and Regards,

Rohan

Answer (score 0):

You'll have to set the `checkChangedListener` on Checkbox and in `onCheckedchanged()` calculate the amount accordingly.

```
int amount = 200;
    CheckBox cb1 = (CheckBox) findViewById(R.id.CheckBox01); 
    cb1.setOnCheckedChangeListener(new OnCheckedChangeListener() { 

    @Override 
    public void onCheckedChanged(CompoundButton buttonView, 
    boolean isChecked) { 
    // TODO Auto-generated method stub 
    if (buttonView.isChecked()) { 
        amount = amount + 50;
    } 
    else 
    { 
        amount = amount - 50;
    } 

    } 
    });

    CheckBox cb2 = (CheckBox) findViewById(R.id.CheckBox02); 
    cb2.setOnCheckedChangeListener(new OnCheckedChangeListener() { 

    @Override 
    public void onCheckedChanged(CompoundButton buttonView, 
    boolean isChecked) { 
    // TODO Auto-generated method stub 
    if (buttonView.isChecked()) { 
        amount = amount + 100;
    } 
    else 
    { 
        amount = amount - 100;
    } 

    } 
    });
```